# How to add paper formats to Windows 10 printer?

Tags: windows-10, printing, printer, network-printer, brother-printer

<sup>*Custom paper sizes were so easy in old Windows versions, but Windows 10 is

so frustratingly "friendly" that such settings are incredibly difficult to find. Argh!*</sup>

**TL;DR:** How can I add paper sizes in Windows 10?!

My printer (Brother MFC-J895DW) is on my home LAN, and my Windows 10 has detected it just fine. However, only certain paper formats are offered, and I see no way to add custom sizes to this list. Specifically, I want to add "Envelope C6".

[image]

Googling gave [this Microsoft help page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/printer-is-configured-to-use-the-wrong-paper-size-ee2ee88a-95fa-f15a-0517-611ec20ffd26) which says to open the printer properties and then click the tap "Paper". Of course, my Windows does not have a tab "Paper", and the tab "Device Settings" that lets me select the paper sizes only allows that same, fixed list:

[image]

The "Brother Utilities" and "Brother Control Center 4" that can be installed as part of the [full driver and software package](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=mfcj895dw_us_eu&os=10013) do not offer any controls for paper sizes; these programs only offers settings for the scanner function.

Googling more, I can see that other people have [printers with more paper options](https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/56550-changing-default-paper-size.html). This one has the "Envelope C6" I am looking for. Of course it would be silly to have to purchase a new printer just because this list is different! Surely *even Windows 10* has a way to specify these sizes??!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to computer settings - printer settings - print server settings. you can then add new paper size to the list of forms. That new form size should then be available to all connected printers.

Comment: "Computer Settings" = you mean the "Settings" app? I do not see any "print server settings" = https://imgur.com/a/4ApXHRv

Comment: You are incorrectly trying to do this under the properties for the specific printer.  It's actually under the printers and  devices tab under what used to be the control panel. You click the start button, go to printers and devices, then click FILE - Server properties.

Comment: Sorry but I don't use Win10. But you were close. While you were in "Printers and Scanners" scroll on down to "related settings" and you should see  "print server settings". click that and you should be able to add your paper size.

Comment: I still do not see any "print server settings" nor "server properties": here's what I see: https://imgur.com/a/EfVBKK5

Comment: Print server properties is just visible, at the top right of your 2nd screen shot. I appears after you click on any printer.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem with my Brother MFC-L3710CW.  I can see from your screenshot that you're using the "Microsoft IPP Driver."  Switch to the "Advanced" tab in the "Printer Properties" dialog and you will see an option to select the driver.
[image]

Switching mine from "Microsoft IPP Class Driver" to "Brother Laser Type1 Class Driver" opened up all of the available paper formats for my printer.

Answer (score -1):

If you need the paper size for a PDF only, you can set custom page sizes in Word directly under *Layout > Size > More Paper Sizes*